# How to implement WPF DataGrid Sorting event by following MVVM pattern?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

How to implement Sorting in WPF DataGrid based on MVVM pattern?

DataGrid Contains the following columns:
1. Software
2. Version
3. TypeOfSoftware
4. ActivatedOn
5. Status
6. Actions [Activate, Deactivate etc]

Requirement:
1. When the Primary(TypeOfSoftware, ActivatedOn, Status) sorted column has duplicated values, use the values in the 'Software' column to determine the secondary sort order. When that column also has duplicated values, use the 'Version' column for the tertiary sort oder.

When applying secondary or tertiary sorting, the sort direction should match the primary sort column (i.e., all ascending or all descending).

Comment: Is the order fix or can the the user change the sorting order?
And is the content of the collection fix? like no changes of entry count?

Comment: Sorting order is same. It may be required to add some new column.
You can consider the following scenarious 1. TypeOfSoftware (ASC) - Software (ASC) - Version (ASC)  2. TypeOfSoftware (DESC) - Software (ASC) - Version (ASC)  3. ActivatedOn (ASC) - Software (ASC) - Version (ASC)  4. ActivatedOn (Desc) - Software (ASC) - Version (ASC) like this way for other column

Comment: Have a look for (CollectionView)[http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html]